# Пуш массивов в массив создает массив пустых массивов

Tags: javascript

Голову сломал.

Сначала в цикле `for`: `for (var j = 0; j <= 7; j++)` я `push` `current_position.push(j);` В итоге генерируется примерно такой массив:

```
var current_position = [];
var cursor = 0; 

function queens8() {
    for (var j = 0; j <= 7; j++) {
        if (check(cursor, j) == true) {

            cursor++;
            current_position.push(j);

            if (current_position.length == 8) {

                done_positions.push(current_position);

                console.log(current_position);    
                //выводит на первой итерации: [0, 4, 7, 5, 2, 6, 1, 3]

            }
            queens8();
        }
    }
    current_position.splice(cursor-1, 1);
    cursor--;
    return;
}
```

Но если собрать все массивы в другой вот так:

```
done_positions.push(current_position);
```

Я получаю примерно такое:

```
[Array[0], Array[0], Array[0], Array[0], Array[0], Array[0], ...]
```

И так все 120 проходов. Почему они пустые и как сделать их не пустыми?

---

UPDATE: Я исправил проблему, но не понимаю почему это сработало:

```
done_positions.push([]+current_position);
```

Comment: Окей, бред. Я исправил это дописав `done_positions.push([]+current_position);` Что!? Почему так?

Comment: А что в переменных нам знать не обязательно, телепаты же :)

Comment: @Other все данные переменных заносятся в коде выше, ничего более не происходит с массивами, переменная `j` генерируется циклом `for`. А уже условия отбора и вноса `j` в массив тут не обязательны и будут только засорять чистоту кода. Я так предполагал и потому сократил код максимально сколько возможно.

Comment: Что такое `current_position`, где создается, как там может быть `[0, 4, 7, 5, 2, 6, 1, 3]`? "Мое недоумение разделяла вся Европа" В.Ерофеев

Comment: @Igor добавил в вопрос всю функцию, теперь в ней точно все действия над массивами.

Comment: А функция `check`?

Comment: @Other, функция `check()` возвращает `true` или `false` и все, какая разница что она возвращает? В ней слишком много кода, а для примера можно допустить что она возвращает поочередно `true` и `false` Суть все-равно в том что массив не добавляется правильно, а исправилось это подозрительным для меня способом. Обьяснение того почему это сработало теперь и будет ответом..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что `done_positions.push([]+current_position);` помещает в `done_positions` новый элемент, являющийся объединением строковых представлений `[]` и `current_position` - на момент исполнения этой строки. А раньше Вы добавляли в `done_positions` ссылку на один и тот же массив много раз.

*Update*

Да, `done_positions.push([current_position]);` создает новый массив из одного элемента, но элементом этим будет все время тот же самый `current_position`.

Вам нужно:

```
done_positions.push(current_position.slice());
```

или

```
done_positions.push(current_position);
current_position = [];
```

Comment: Что значит ссылку? А что если сделать `done_positions.push([current_position]);`? Это ведь тоже по логике добавляет массив?

Comment: Я никак не пойму. Как может быть один и тот же массив когда он меняется каждый круг цикла?

Comment: @Levelleor В Вашем коде массив `current_position` создается один раз в строке `var current_position = [];`. Потом это один и тот же объект, в котором Вы добавляете и удаляете элементы.